# How Do I Track the Install Source from within an Ionic App?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, ionic3

Marketing specialists keep instructing my client to setup the analytics so that it can track where the user is being referred from so that we can optimize the advertising campaigns.

When I ask them how to setup the tracking correctly they send me to a link for the native Android & iOS google analytics libraries and provide the settings.  I respond in kind stating that our app is not built using the native SDK's it is built using the Ionic Framework. They then have no response for this.

I have Google Analytics implemented as well as Facebook analytics. Both systems are actively tracking data. But apparently it is still not tracking the source of which advertising campaign the user originated from and / or installed the app from.

I've tried to find an example of this somewhere and talked to numerous people but from what I can tell it is not possible using the Ionic Framework.

Can anyone provide some insight into this? If this is not possible it seems like a rather large issue with the Ionic Platform that should be made more visible.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try firebase [plugin for ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase)?

Comment: I haven't gotten around to trying that yet as we are not using Firebase Analytics.

Comment: are you using this [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-analytics)?

Comment: Yes we are using the google analytics ionic plugin.

Comment: did you try checking the datasource variable `window.ga.getVar('ds', () => {});` as stated [here](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it will at least give me some things to try.

Comment: @JamesParker Did you find a way to accomplish the campaign tracking?